# Laravel protect function against "refresh" page

Tags: php, laravel, page-refresh

When i open the web page, laravel via my custom class and function send me to text message on my mobile, but its possible to block sending when i press F5 or refresh web page ?

`controller`

```
public function index()
{
    $phoneNumber = $user['mobile_phone'];
    $smsMessage= $user['smsMessage'];
    SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber, $smsMessage);

    return view('welcome');
}
```

Comment: Are you sending message on welcome page only?

Comment: @ Harpal Singh yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sending message only when user visit welcome page, then you can set a flag in session and check if session value is not exists only then send message.

```
use Session;
public function index()
{
    if(!Session::has('message_sent')){
       SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber, $smsMessage);
       Session::put('message_sent', true);
     }
    
    return view('welcome');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function index()
{
   if(url()->previous()!=url()->current()){
      SendTextMessage::SendMessage($phoneNumber, $smsMessage);
   }

   
    return view('welcome');
}
```

URL history is stored in session, so it can be a solution for page refresh.